# How to put translations from Developer Console in an android app's resource file?

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play-services, translation

I paid for translation services from the Google Play Developer Console and all of the languages were translated successfully. I successfully translated my app's store listing description into 9 languages.

But how does one go about translating all of the strings in `strings.xml`? I downloaded a file with all of the translated strings, but what do I do with this and where do I put it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll be needing to create separate folders for strings.xml that contains the different languages. You can see/read this from the [How to Create Alternative Resources](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html) guide:

> 1. res/values/strings.xml    Contains English text for all the strings that the application uses, including text for a string named title.
> 2. res/values-fr/strings.xml    Contain French text for all the strings, including title.
> 3. res/values-ja/strings.xml    Contain Japanese text for all the strings except title.
>
> If your Java code refers to R.string.title, here is what will happen
>   at runtime:
>
> If the device is set to any language other than French, Android will
>   load title from the res/values/strings.xml file. If the device is set
>   to French, Android will load title from the res/values-fr/strings.xml
>   file.

Check this [Multilingual app tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/07/android-building-multi-language-supported-app/) for a hands-on experience.